# Is there a way to perform test against AWS "StatusCheckFailed_System" alarm

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to configure a aws cloudwatch alarm for "StatusCheckFailed_System". I am purposely looking for this whenever underlying hardware failure detects, I can recover the instance without having a downtime.

There are MS SQL database servers which are standalone and not a part of autoscaling group. But obvious AWS wont force to go down their underlying hardware so by any chance I can test StatusCheckFailed_System? Kindly advise.

Regards,
Sagar

Answer (score 1):

Oh yes.. I got it..

Can you try this

```
aws cloudwatch set-alarm-state \
--alarm-name "ec2_system_alarm" \
 --state-value ALARM \ --state-reason
 "simulate an ec2 system failure"
```

Got reference from [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/5t2tny/how_to_simulate_instance_system_status_check/)

But this will just change the alarm state and not actually change the check of your ec2 instance.

Comment: HI Pratik, 
This will trigger Instance reachability failed and not the system check failed which I am looking for. Recover instance type will only work with "StatusCheckFailed_System" and not with "StatusCheckFailed_Instance".

Any other way?

Comment: Yes i got what you are saying.. Did some more digging and found this.. Have updated it in the answer

Comment: Yes, tried that but it didn't work. As per AWS feedback this will reassess the instance for data before triggering the actions. In short, there is no other a way to test StatusCheckFailed_System.